# htaccess rewrite rule to remove subfolders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I want to change

```
example.com/modules/page/page.php
```

to

```
example.com/page
```

I have a RewriteRule that works partially, but there's a problem.

```
RewriteRule ^page/(\w+)/? modules/page/page.php?page_id=$1 [NC,L]
```

page.php can be accessed if I type `example.com/page/randomstring`

I want this to be valid for only `example.com/page`

How can I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your .htaccess file

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([A-Za-z0-9]+)$ modules/page/page.php?page_id=$1 [L,QSA]
```